# Use case relationship with actor

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

if A is extension use case (not base use case), can A be directly referenced by the actor?

Comment: Look, we all hate UML, why down him for it?

Answer (score 1):

YES
The user can as said above, but does not indirectly reference/use it, it must be explicitly modeled.

Drive Truck extends Drive Steering Based Vehicle.  It make sense that the Actor could reference either.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the case that there are two kinds of use cases:

- Abstract -- not directly experience by an actor, but extensions ("subclasses") are.
- Concrete -- experienced by an actor.

Comment: in use-case terminology, I don't think extensions are like subclasses, they're more like 'alternate paths'

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe: the "alternate" is roughly analogous to a subclass which overrides selected steps.  Use Cases are defined as being object-oriented by Jacobson.  They're not literally classes, but there are intentional parallels.

Comment: @[S.Lott]: use-cases have a Generalization relationship, different from Extends (see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cextend.html) - but i think i agree with your analogy, extension points are like overridden methods...

Comment: Extension points are really like conditionally inserted methods, rather than overridden methods.

Answer (score 0):

yes; the fact that A extends some other use-case does not 'hide' it from actors